# Sums of reciprocals of powers of the imaginary part of the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, polynomials, power-series, riemann-zeta

To investigate the relations between Appell / Jensen polynomials and the real-valued function for real $t$

$$\Omega(t) = \xi(1/2+it)/\xi(1/2),$$

where $\xi(s)$ is the Landau Riemann xi function, I need reasonable approximations, say to 3 significant digits, of

$$ Tr_{2n}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/(z_k)^{2n}$$

for $n=1,2,3,4$ where the $z_k$ are the imaginary parts of the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function above the real axis. (Assume the RH is true, of course.)

I don't have access to Mathematica nor Maple, so help would be appreciated.

Edit (June 5, 2020):

To allay any further doubts about the convergence of $Tr_2$:

Titchmarsh in his classic book On the Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function has, on p. 18, Eqn 2.1.14

$$\Xi(z)= \xi(1/2+iz),$$

and on p. 30 he states that it is an even integral function of order 1, whose exponent of convergence is 1. "Hence $\Xi(z)$ has an infinity of zeros, whose exponent of convergence is 1. The same is true of $\xi(s).$" In his Theory of Functions on p. 249 is

Theorem 8.22: If $r_1, r_2...$ are the moduli of the roots of $f(z)$, then the series $\sum 1/r^{\alpha}$ is convergent if $\alpha > \rho.$

$\rho$ in an earlier paragraph is called the order of the integral function $f(z)$.

The absolute contribution of a zero of $\Omega$, $a+ib$, and its complex conjugate to the sum of the inverse squares of the zeros is $2(a^2-b^2)/(a^2+b^2)^2=2\cos(2\theta)/r^2$ with $\theta=0$ for the real zeros. This is less than $2/r^{\alpha}$ for $0< \alpha < 2$, so the trace of the paired inverse squares, even including any complex zeros if they were to be found, is absolutely convergent

Comment: Do you know for certain that those series converge?

Comment: $(s-1)\zeta$ is entire order $1$ (and maximal type of course) so $\sum 1/|z_k|^{1+\epsilon}$ will converge for any $\epsilon>0$ (which is the same as the OP sum since the real parts of the non-trivial zeroes are bounded regardless of RH)  while of course $\sum 1/|z_k|= \infty$ and only the symmetric sum of the critical zeroes reciprocals converges conditionally (here we can consider trivial roots as they do not affect much, or take the symmetric from of $\zeta$ which gets rid of those)

Comment: @Conrad, I was a little more careful in deciphering my old notes. Everything seems consistent now. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: excellent - and thanks for pointing to that article by Coffey which seems interesting

Comment: @Conrad, all related to the fascinating history of ideas presented in "Zeros of entire Fourier transforms"  by Dimitrov and Rusev.

Comment: The Dimitrov/Rusev is a good survey - haven't seen it before so again many thanks

Comment: Hey, just why was Gottfried's answer downvoted? Accurate, concise, timely, and correct with more info than I asked, but relevant info.

Comment: Another excellent survey: "On some historical aspects of the theory of Riemann zeta function" by Iurato.

Comment: See also the MO-Q https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362153/derivatives-of-riemann-xi-and-traces-of-zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just to make things visible and to help towards a hypothese (well aware of the comment of Gerry Myerson):* I've somewhere found online the set of first *100 000* values of the imaginary parts to *8* digits. Partial sums in increasing segments of $2^k$ are the following:

```
   partial sums of sum(i=1,2*2^k-1, 1/(imag(root_i))^(2n)   

   k     n=1             n=2                 n=3                  n=4
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0  0.00500524412341  0.0000250524687349  0.000000125393721912  0.000000000627626189713
   1  0.00886667676944  0.0000327283874871  0.000000141065528135  0.000000000660375162896
   2   0.0121739737744  0.0000356030857633  0.000000143677509519  0.000000000662837761448
   3   0.0150045293315  0.0000366728779872  0.000000144108076453  0.000000000663021051125
   4   0.0172998726364  0.0000370263290034  0.000000144166228966  0.000000000663031185306
   5   0.0190794372367  0.0000371333200692  0.000000144173144661  0.000000000663031660997
   6   0.0203971381635  0.0000371628546828  0.000000144173860457  0.000000000663031679531
   7   0.0213326190435  0.0000371703457908  0.000000144173925660  0.000000000663031680139
   8   0.0219725965445  0.0000371721091123  0.000000144173930966  0.000000000663031680156
   9   0.0223966100709  0.0000371724981445  0.000000144173931358  0.000000000663031680157
  10   0.0226699376045  0.0000371725793391  0.000000144173931384  0.000000000663031680157
  11   0.0228420530479  0.0000371725955004  0.000000144173931386  0.000000000663031680157
  12   0.0229482871375  0.0000371725985893  0.000000144173931386  0.000000000663031680157
  13   0.0230127402289  0.0000371725991596  0.000000144173931386  0.000000000663031680157
  14   0.0230512683394  0.0000371725992617  0.000000144173931386  0.000000000663031680157
  15   0.0230740041036  0.0000371725992795  0.000000144173931386  0.000000000663031680157
```

*update* corrected wrong upper index in sum-expression
*update2* corrected the mention in the partial sums protocol, that the sums are of course from the powers of the **imaginary** part of root_i alone.

Comment: Nice, Gottfried. Thanks very much. However, Coffey gives $\xi(1/2)^{(2)}$ as approx. 0.022972 from an integral calculation and this should be equal to $Tr_2$ from manipulating the log derivative of the  Hadamard product formula for xi. Since your partial sums exceed this, it suggests the series is not convergent. So there is an inconsistency somewhere between my analysis, Conrad's comment, and your partial sums. (I had initially erroneously assumed gaps of at least one between consecutive large $z_k$, ensuring convergence, but this gap assumption is not true.)

Comment: P. 529 of "Relations and positivity results for the derivatives of the Riemann $\xi$ function" by Coffey.

Comment: @Tom not sure what is the inconsistency - the sum for $n=1$ (which is the reciprocal of the squares as the sum is $2n$) is pretty close to the Coffey result - also here we use only the reciprocals of the imaginary parts from what I see, while there I think there is a little extra from the small real part, so it makes sense that the sum here is slightly (but only so) higher - the fact about the sums of the reciprocals of zeroes converging from $1+\epsilon$ on is just classic entire functions theory that is found in any book on the subject (eg Levin, Boas etc)

Comment: @TomCopeland - hmm, that's curious. May be that with 100 000 numbers of the first zeros the cutting to 8 digits becomes significant? Other way it may be that the given numbers for the zeros are not correct at all, don't have the source at hand. (I can provide them in Pari/GP-format as I've converted them from the download years ago if you need them).

Comment: Okay, being a little more careful with my old notes:  $$Tr_2 =  \xi^{(2)}(1/2) / (2\xi(1/2)) \simeq .022972/(2 \cdot .497)  \simeq .02311$$, so everything is consistent.

Comment: Certainly, a slow convergence! An asymptotic expansion would be better.

Comment: Yes, I'd looked at the convergence in the following way: count number/index of roots until the fifth digit of the partial sum changes. The critical indexes increase long time very softly and in the near fromm 10 000 roots explode to add only 1 significant digits at the 5'th position... I didn't find any meaningful guess, what sort of function this behave could imply.

Comment: Second sanity check:
  $$12(Tr_2^2-Tr_4) \simeq 12((.02311)^2-.0000372) \simeq.005962$$ equal to

$$\xi^{(4)}(1/2)/\xi(1/2) \simeq .0.002963/.497  \simeq .005962.$$

Comment: @Tom - cheers! Very well, everything.... :-)

Comment: Conversely, using the Faber polynomials, we can tease out the traces from the coefficients of $\Omega$; e.g., recalling that  $$\Omega^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^n \xi^{(n)}(1/2)/\xi(1/2),$$ then

$$2 Tr_4 = -4 \Omega^{(4)}(0)/4! + 2 (\Omega^{(2)}(0)/2)^2$$

$$ \simeq -4 \cdot .005962/4! + 2 (-.04622/2)^2  \simeq .00007448,$$ and from Gottfried $$2Tr_4 \simeq 2 \cdot .000037173 = .00007436.$$

Comment: I cleaned up and deleted most of my comments. I'd like to thank you again for an excellent, quick answer.